# Heroku Login unable to verify the first certificate vscode/nodejs

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, visual-studio-code

**Summary**

Trying to login to heroku get Warning: unable to verify the first certificate. I attempt the login anyway and get Error: unable to verify the first certificate.

**What I've done**

I've been trying to use VS Code so that I can have the flexibility of extensions. Instead of using .cmd or powershell. I changed my setting so that I could use git bash which I'm more familiar with using:
*"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "F:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\bash.exe".*

I downloaded git and nodejs with no problems.I created SSH key but saved it on the default location
*/c/Users/rawle/.ssh/id_rsa*.

I downloaded heroku(64 bit) version and saved it to my F Drive Program files
where I had also saved vscode,nodejs, git.

When I check my heroku version I get (heroku/7.16.0 win32-x64 node-v8.12.0)
I can use commands like heroku --help and heroku --version but anything I would need to be authenticated for give me the "unable to verify first certificate". While I have searched other stack questions none seem to have an answer for this when using heroku and nodejs and logging in. I have uninstalled and installed and done heroku update several times with no luck. Can anyone tell me how to solve this error?